# How do I move a pointer in a vector of pointers to another index in that vector?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

Edit:

Thank you for the help. I also thought of using nullptr which should work:

v.at(1).ptr = v.at(0).ptr;

followed by

v.at(0).ptr = nullptr;

---

I am working on a project in C++ and I have a vector of pointers of a class I made

The vector is size 64 and contains pointers of type L

Suppose the vector is called v

Suppose I have Pointer 1 in the first index of the vector (v.at(0))

I want to move Pointer 1 to the second index of the vector (v.at(1))

Here comes my current code:

`v.at(1) = v.at(0);`

First question: is this the correct way to set the second index to hold the pointer currently stored in my first index ?

Second question: how do I stop my first index from holding my pointer ?

Thank you in advance ! :D

Answer (score 0):

This would work with a swap algorithm. I.e.

```cpp
// Swaps the entries at indices A and B in vector<L*> v
void swap(int idxA, int idxB)
{
    L* temp = v.at(idxA);
    v.at(idxA) = v.at(idxB);
    v.at(idxB) = temp;
}
```

Comment: `std::swap` exists. Just saying…

Comment: Thank you, this helps. I also thought of using nullptr. Would v.at(newIndex) = v.at(oldIndex); and v.at(oldIndex).ptr = nullptr; also work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Then use `std::swap`:

```
std::swap(v.at(i_a), v.at(i_b));
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps. I also thought of using nullptr. Would v.at(newIndex) = v.at(oldIndex); and v.at(oldIndex).ptr = nullptr; also work ?

Comment: @HusamChekfa: That's something different than swap. Swap makes the values in the two location switch places. What you do there with the nullptr is an exchange. Also helpfully implemented by the STL: `std::exchange` which would apply to what you're asking about as `v.at(newIndex) = std::exchange(v.at(oldIndex), nullptr))`

Comment: I see, so v.at(newIndex).ptr = std::exchange(v.at(oldIndex).ptr, nullptr) would first copy the ptr value at oldIndex to the ptr value at newIndex, then set oldIndex ptr to nullptr ?

Comment: @HusamChekfa exactly.